# How to play Gif Images on ubuntu phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, gif

I have the Ubuntu phone Aquaris E4.5 and I can't seem to be able to play gif files with the the gallery app, the images are saved on my memory card fyi, so should it be possible? Do I need a special app for it? Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a strange way, but it works.

1 - Start the Notes App

2 - Add a new note, and attach the .gif from the "gallery"

3 - Done!

Comment: Ok, so after your wonderful answer @ThatOldPencil I figured out a tiny hack, I used the wifi transfer app on the phone to connect to the pc by filezilla and uploaded a bunch of gifs on the phone and then from the wifi transfer app menu you can choose to open any file with the Notes app and it asks you if you want to add to existing note or create a new one and so it gives you possibilites to create tiny gif albums that you can save as notes and view any time from the Notes app !